# How to change where GIMP creates directories (Brushes, Frames, Gradients, etc.)

Tags: gimp, configuration

I am running GIMP 2.10.12 on Windows 10. When I start GIMP, it creates the following directories in `c:/Users/MyName/Documents`:

- `Brushes`
- `Frames`
- `Gradients`
- `Patterns`
- `Shapes`
- `Styled Lines`
- `Textures`
- `Tubes`

I want these directories to be stored in a separate gimp-related directory, not in `Documents`.

Searching led me to [documentation for gimprc](https://www.gimp.org/man/gimprc.html) for version 2.6. But this seems like a dead-end for several reasons (e.g., there are no gimprc entries for items Frames, Styled Lines, Tubes). Lots of search hits show up for creating brushes, gradients, etc. But I cannot find how to tell GIMP to store these things elsewhere. More to the point: how to tell GIMP *not* to create these directories in `Documents`.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can set up your own directories, and add them in GIMP's Preferences under "Folders". More info here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-folders-data

Comment: AFAIK most of these directories (Frames, Shapes, Styles Lines, Textures, Tubes) don't come from Gimp. Have you added any plugin? OTOH PaintshopPro seems to handle such objects...

Comment: @xenoid Right you are! Thanks for your help.